# How to switch GitHub fonts to previous style?

Tags: github

GitHub font in my Chrome was like this:

[image]

And now it is like this:

[image]

Is there any way to switch it back?

Comment: You could at least open your devtools and find out what the names of the new font family is.

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That might not be possible at the moment, as [Steven Popovich](https://github.com/stevepopovich)  explains in this [discussion thread](https://github.com/community/community/discussions/38000) (by [Gani Georgiev](https://github.com/ganigeorgiev)):

> We made a decision to force some of the fonts in the app for layout purposes, but maybe we should revisit it.

That was for GitHub mobile, but it might also have a consequence on the GitHub website itself.

[This discussion](https://github.com/community/community/discussions/39226) (about the website) speaks about the [Noto Sans font](https://fonts.google.com/noto/specimen/Noto+Sans), and suggests using a third-party Chrome plugin [Stylebot](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylebot/oiaejidbmkiecgbjeifoejpgmdaleoha?hl=en) to change locally said font.

Although the same [thread includes](https://github.com/community/community/discussions/39226#discussioncomment-4156008):

> I've just found that you can force a monospace font for the markdown editor that "fixes" the backtick overlap.
>
> You can go to https://github.com/settings/appearance and enable the "`Markdown editor font preference`" at the bottom of the page:
>
> [image: https://camo.githubusercontent.com/a8d9ed07fd00af74c739c34b75e60bd6b56afe7873c0024c5006762d02dce51d/68747470733a2f2f692e696d6775722e636f6d2f4e63426872536a2e706e67]

Comment: That happened in my desktop web browser. Thank you for your complete answer!

Comment: @cavalcantelucas True. The second part of the answer is about the web browser indeed.